# Como faço para realizar o preenchimento de uma informação que está em um tipo complexo JSON?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, modelo-relacional, model

Estou tentando realizar o preenchimento de um tipo ICollection que está como propriedade do meu modelo Professional.

Ao realizar o request eu passo as informações via JSON

[image: request]

Porém no debug do VS e no GET a informação não está lá!

[image: VS]

[image: Get]

Comment: Amigo tenta mudar a propriedade "graduation" para "Graduations" igual está na sua classe, ele só vai popular se os nome estiverem idênticos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Faça como o Maycon citou, seu objeto tem que ter o mesmo nome com as mesmas propriedade com os nomes idênticos que vai dar certo.

Answer (score 0):

O nome das propriedades de seu `json` pode ser igual ao objeto que está recebendo como já citado(Particularmente acho isso horrível, rs). Vou mostrar uma forma mais "elegante" de resolver, utilizando o `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Primeiramente instancie-o em seu projeto:

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Depois em seu objeto

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastname")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cpf")]
    public string Cpf { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("birthDate ")]
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("motherName")]
    public string MotherName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("postalCode")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("adress")]
    public string Adress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("adressNumber")]
    public string AdressNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("complement")]
    public string Complement { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("background")]
    public string Background { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("graduations")]
    public IEnumerable<Graduation> Graduations { get; set; }
}

public class Graduation
{
    [JsonProperty("instituionName")]
    public string InstituionName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("grade")]
    public string Grade { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("formationYear")]
    public string FormationYear { get; set; }
}
```

Seu `Controller`

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] RootObject obj)
{
   // Faz algo aqui 
   return Ok();
}
```

E terá finalmente o tão aguardado resultado, hehe.